# Playing mp4 video in AS3. NetStream was unable to invoke callback onMetaData

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video

I'm trying to play a video in flash player using following code.

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.media.Video;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        public var MyNC:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
        public var MyNS:NetStream;
        public var MyVideo:Video = new Video();

        public function Main() {    
            MyVideo = new Video();
            addChild(MyVideo);
            MyNC = new NetConnection();
            MyNC.connect(null);
            MyNS = new NetStream(MyNC);
            MyVideo.attachNetStream(MyNS);
            MyNS.play("video.mp4");
        }
    }
}
```

It works but shows folowing error:

Error #2044: Unhandled AsyncErrorEvent:. text=Error #2095: flash.net.NetStream was unable to invoke callback onMetaData.

error=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property onMetaData not found on flash.net.NetStream and there is no default value.
    at Main()
Error #2044: Unhandled AsyncErrorEvent:. text=Error #2095: flash.net.NetStream was unable to invoke callback onXMPData.

error=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property onXMPData not found on flash.net.NetStream and there is no default value.
    at Main()

Answer (score 1):

I got this error removed by setting value for MyNS.client

```
listener.onMetaData = function(md:Object):void {};
MyNS.client = listener;
```